# How to query currently logged in user's AD information in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have an MVC4 intranet page and would like to get the `homeDirectory` attribute from Active Directory. Would like to know the fastest way to get an attribute from AD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

   if(user != null)
   {
      // do something here....      
      string homeDrive = user.HomeDrive;
      string homeDirectory = user.HomeDirectory;
   }
}
```

If you're using Windows Authentication in your ASP.NET MVC app, you could also fetch the currently logged in user like this:

```
UserPrincipal currentUser = UserPrincipal.Current;
```

But more often than not, in a web app, this is something like `NETWORK SERVICE` or the `IUSER_machineName` user (and not your user at the browser)...

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Fantastic answer mate! That is exeactlly what I wanted, all the results I found before was to query AD as an LDAP. This is the best. Will try it out. BTW, would you please advise, which way is faster, comparing with search LDAP using sid? SecurityIdentifier sid = windowsId.User;

    using(DirectoryEntry userDe = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<SID=" + sid.Value + ">"))